# Get values from string between group of numbers (as groups/values separator)

Tags: php, regex

I have string containing numeric codes `(ie. 90, 37, 230, 11, ...)` as groups separator.

**For example**

> "**90**49-45**230**SomeText**11**56**37**1...."

How can I get values between this separator codes? The ordering of this separators `(90|37|230|11|...)` is random. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a regular expression from an array of numeric codes?

Answer (score 0):

This functions demonstrates the way to go. Keep in mind, that you may need to escape the delimites, see [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-quote.php)

```
function splitByMultipleDelimiters(array $delimiters, $string)
{
    $pattern = '(' . implode('|', $delimiters) . ')';

    return preg_split($pattern, $string);
}

$delimiters = array(90, 37, 230, 11);
$input = '9049-45230SomeText1156371';

var_dump(splitByMultipleDelimiters($delimiters, $input));
```

Comment: Problem is, that part of value can contain group separator :-( Ie. **90**49-90**230**SomeText**11**56371...